# Conda UnsatisfiableError (for antibody humanization)

Tags: python, conda, bioconda

I am trying to run biophi in anaconda to humanize antibodies  (https://github.com/Merck/BioPhi). I am very new to this so already after trying to get biophi running I encounter the following error.

```
UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be incompatible with each other:

Output in format: Requested package -> Available versions

The following specifications were found to be incompatible with your system:

  - feature:/win-64::__win==0=0
  - feature:|@/win-64::__win==0=0
  - biophi -> click[version='>=7'] -> __unix
  - biophi -> click[version='>=7'] -> __win

Your installed version is: 0
```

Thank you in advance!

I tried installing click using pip install click, which seems to work, but doesnt resolve the error message. I am running this in windows and not in unix/linux.

Answer (score 1):

The [defined software environment](https://github.com/Merck/BioPhi/blob/55440a0b6d561375f26d283c7425042ccd084288/environment.yml) ultimately depends on `hmmer`, which is only available through Bioconda and only supports Linux and macOS.

Windows users who wish to use Bioconda have the option of either using WSL2 to run Linux or a container system, like Docker. You will need to install a Linux version of Conda **base** in the subsystem/container. I recommend Miniforge to all bioinformaticians.